# MongodbMessageSource in Spring integration is throwing error with no beanFactory

Tags: spring-integration, spring-dsl

> **This is my code snippet**

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "topicChannel", outputChannel="responseChannel")
public Employee getEmpDetails() throws Exception {
      Expression query = new LiteralExpression("{'name' : '*****'}");
      MongoDbMessageSource source = new MongoDbMessageSource(mongoDbFactory(), query);
      source.setEntityClass(Employee.class);
      source.afterPropertiesSet();
      List<Employee> resluts =((List<Employee>)source.receive().getPayload());
      return resluts.get(0);
    }
```

**Below is the error**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No beanfactory
>           at org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils.createStandardEvaluationContext(ExpressionUtils.java:79)
>           at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.inbound.MongoDbMessageSource.onInit(MongoDbMessageSource.java:176)
>           at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:150)
>           at com.gap.si.configuratoin.MongoDBConfiguration.getEmpDetails(MongoDBConfiguration.java:48)
>           at com.gap.si.configuratoin.MongoDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e22c38.CGLIB$getEmpDetails$3()
>           at com.gap.si.configuratoin.MongoDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e22c38$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$99782c25.invoke()
>           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
>           at com.gap.si.configuratoin.MongoDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e22c38.getEmpDetails()
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>           at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.resolveTargetBeanFromMethodWithBeanAnnotation(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:362)
>           at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.ServiceActivatorAnnotationPostProcessor.createHandler(ServiceActivatorAnnotationPostProcessor.java:54)
>           at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:117)
>           at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor$1.doWith(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:151)
>           at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:495)
>           at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:502)
>           at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:131)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
>           at com.gap.si.configuratoin.Application.main(Application.java:16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the `MongoDbMessageSource` as a `@Bean` too so that it is properly initialized by the framework; calling `afterPropertiesSet()` is not enough.

Also, when a `@ServiceActivator` is a `@Bean`, the bean type must be `MessageHandler`. For a POJO `@ServiceActivator` method, use a `@MessageEndoint`.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your reply.. Second point is bit confusing as a newbie to this. Please explain with some example.

Comment: Please read the [documentation about annotated endpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations) and come back if you have specific questions.

Comment: Now i can able to get results from DB, method is thowing error as "Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.Void] for method match". Code snippet is [link](http://pastebin.com/Fdx16ieG)

Comment: You should use `@InboundChannelAdapter` bean for the `MessageSource` . See the [first example here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#d4e15193).